# I am getting No response received. Timed Out. No response message is shown

Tags: jms, message-queue

```java
connection = (MQQueueConnection) mqQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///" + requestQueueName);
MQQueue responseQueue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///" + responeQueueName);
MQQueueSender sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(responseQueue);

isConnected = true;

System.out.println("-------- preparing request to send: ");

String messageString = requestString;

JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage(messageString);
message.setJMSType("XML/MQ");
// message.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);

connection.start();

sender.send(message);
JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(TIMEOUT);
System.out.println("-------- recieved JMSMessage is: \n" + receivedMessage);
sender.close();
receiver.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
System.out.println("-------- getting response: ");
responseXMLString = receivedMessage != null ? ((JMSTextMessage) receivedMessage).getText() : "No response recieved. Timed Out";
```

Comment: Is there another component which actually consumes the request message from `queue` and puts a response message onto `responseQueue`? If not, you won't just magically receive a message from `responseQueue`. Also, you're not doing anything to actually correlate the response with the request. You could easily get this mixed up if there is high message throughput.

Comment: Did you set the proper host, port and qmgr name in your mqQueueConnectionFactory ? The creation code for your mqQueueConnectionFactory is missing...